# `find` with `rename` – No such file or directory

Tags: linux, find, rename

I want to remove dot in filenames in subdirectories. I use `rename` and `find`:

```
 find . -type f -name '*.avi' -exec rename 's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/ /g' {} \;
```

The command `find` works alone. The command `rename` works alone. But when I use both together, I get an error:

```
No such file or directory
```

How to make them work together?

---

I tested this but it doesn't work:

```
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir f1
cd f1
touch {1..20}-file.with.dot.avi
cd ..
cp -r  f1/ f2
cd ..
find . -type f -name '*.avi' -exec  rename   's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/ /g' "{}" \;
```

---

I test this but don't work

```
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir f1
cd f1
touch {1..20}-file.with.dot.avi
cd ..
cp -r  f1/ f2
cd ..
find . -type f -name '*.avi' -exec  rename   's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/ /g' "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note [there are many `rename`s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618). The OP's `rename` seems to be the Perl `rename` (sometimes referred to as `prename`). In general `rename` [may or may not run the Perl `rename`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22577767/10765659).

---

The errors are like:

```
Can't rename ./test/f1/1-file.with.dot.avi  /test/f1/1-file with dot.avi: No such file or directory
```

Note the target path makes no sense. It looks absolute but in fact it doesn't start with `/`. It starts with a space character. This is because the leading dot (`.`) was replaced by a space character. There is no directory `<space>/test/f1/` and `rename` will not create it, hence `No such file or directory`.

The dot was there because `find` is obliged to start pathnames with one of the paths the user provides, and you provided `.` as a path.

There are few solutions:

- Do not use `.` as a starting path. E.g.:

  ```
  find "$PWD" -type f -name '*.avi' -exec rename 's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/ /g' {} \;
  ```

  Note if there's a dot in any directory name (in what `$PWD` expands to or in some directory below) then you will most likely hit the same problem.
- Re-add the missing dot:

  ```
  find . -type f -name '*.avi' -exec rename 's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/ /g; s/^ /./' {} \;
  ```

  This is not a general solution. Again, expect problems if any pathname contains a directory component with `.`.
- If your `find` supports `-execdir`, use it. The resulting pathnames will be like `./1-file.with.dot.avi` and dots in directory names will become irrelevant. Still you will need to deal with this leading dot. Examples:

  ```
  # re-adding dot like in the above approach
  find . -type f -name '*.avi' -execdir rename 's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/ /g; s/^ /./' {} \;
  # or stripping ./ first
  find . -type f -name '*.avi' -execdir rename 's|^\./||; s/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/ /g' {} \;
  ```

  POSIX solution to emulate `-execdir` where it's unavailable requires running a shell. Possible approach:

  ```
  find . -type f -name '*.avi' -exec sh -c '
     cd "$(dirname "$2")" && rename "$1" "$(basename "$2")"
  ' find-sh 's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/ /g' {} \;
  ```

  Notes:

  - `rename` itself is not a POSIX tool;
  - I chose to pass `s/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/ /g` as a separate argument to `sh` instead of embedding it in the single-quoted shell code and worrying about proper nesting the quotes.
- Improve your expression so it doesn't alter directory components (including the leading dot), only the filename (the string after the last `/` in the pathname). I'm not good enough with regular expressions to help you with this.

Answer (score -1):

Do your directory or file names have spaces?  It may be throwing off the command `-exec` builds and hands to the shell.

Try adding quotes around the braces so any filenames with spaces aren't treated as separate parameters by the shell:

```
find . -type f -name '*.avi' -exec  rename   's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/ /g' "{}" \;
```

Comment: I add quotes but the commands display always  no such file or directory.

Comment: -1 Snake oil. `{}` doesn't have to be quoted. `-exec` does not spawn a shell (unless you explicitly tell it so, e.g. `-exec sh …`). The tool replaces `{}` by the current pathname and passes it to the utility (`rename` in this case) as a single argument without word splitting. There is no shell between `find` and `rename`.